# Error Code 1 when trying to insert video along with its details into mysql database in php

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to make youtube clone website in php. I am stuck at a stage where i want to insert video that i am trying to upload into mysql database but it says error code 1. My project structure is as follows in below image

[image: My Project structure]

Screenshot of my website when i upload the entry as below

[image: Tried Work]

When click on upload button, i get the error as below image

[image: Error]

Here is my upto date code that i have tried.

index.php File:

```
<?php require_once("includes/header.php"); ?>

<?php require_once("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

header.php file:

```
<?php require_once("includes/config.php"); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>VideoTube</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/commonActions.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="pageContainer">
    <!-- Master Head Container -->
    <div id="mastHeadContainer">
      <!-- Hamburger Menu Button -->
      <button class="navShowHide">
        <img src="assets/images/icons/menu.png">
      </button> <!--End of Hamburger Menu Button -->

      <!-- Site Logo -->
      <a class="logoContainer" href="index.php">
        <img src="assets/images/icons/VideoTubeLogo.png" title="logo" alt="Site logo">
      </a> <!-- End of Site Logo -->

      <!-- Search Bar -->
      <div class="searchBarContainer">
        <form action="search.php" method="GET">
          <input type="text" class="searchBar" name="term" placeholder="Search...">
          <button class="searchButton">
            <img src="assets/images/icons/search.png">
          </button>
        </form>
      </div> <!-- End of Search Bar -->

      <!-- Right Icons Area -->
      <div class="rightIcons">
        <a href="upload.php">
          <img class="upload" src="assets/images/icons/upload.png">
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <img class="upload" src="assets/images/profilePictures/default.png">
        </a>
      </div> <!-- End of Right Icons Area -->
    </div> <!-- End of Master Head Container -->

    <div id="sideNavContainer" style="display:none;">

    </div>
    <div id="mainSectionContainer">
      <div id="mainContentContainer">
```

footer.php file:

```
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

config.php file:

```
<?php
ob_start(); // turns on output buffering

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");

try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:dbname=VideoTube;host=localhost", "root", "");
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

VideoDetailsFormProvider.php file:

```
<?php
class VideoDetailsFormProvider {

    private $con;

    public function __construct($con) {
        $this->con = $con;
    }

    public function createUploadForm() {
        $fileInput = $this->createFileInput();
        $titleInput = $this->createTitleInput();
        $descriptionInput = $this->createDescriptionInput();
        $privacyInput = $this->createPrivacyInput();
        $categoriesInput = $this->createCategoriesInput();
        $uploadButton = $this->createUploadButton();
        return "<form action='processing.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                    $fileInput
                    $titleInput
                    $descriptionInput
                    $privacyInput
                    $categoriesInput
                    $uploadButton
                </form>";
    }

    private function createFileInput() {

        return "<div class='form-group'>
                    <input type='file' class='form-control-file' id='exampleFormControlFile1' name='fileInput' required>
                </div>";
    }

    private function createTitleInput() {
        return "<div class='form-group'>
                    <input class='form-control' type='text' placeholder='Title' name='titleInput'>
                </div>";
    }

    private function createDescriptionInput() {
        return "<div class='form-group'>
                    <textarea class='form-control' placeholder='Description' name='descriptionInput' rows='3'></textarea>
                </div>";
    }

    private function createPrivacyInput() {
        return "<div class='form-group'>
                    <select class='form-control' name='privacyInput'>
                        <option value='0'>Private</option>
                        <option value='1'>Public</option>
                    </select>
                </div>";
    }

    private function createCategoriesInput() {
        $query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories");    
        $query->execute();

        $html = "<div class='form-group'>
                    <select class='form-control' name='categoryInput'>";

        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $id = $row["id"];
            $name = $row["name"];

            $html .= "<option value='$id'>$name</option>";
        }

        $html .= "</select>
                </div>";

        return $html;

    }

    private function createUploadButton() {
        return "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='uploadButton'>Upload</button>";
    }
}
?>
```

VideoProcessor.php file:

```
<?php
class VideoProcessor {

    private $con;
    private $sizeLimit = 500000000;
    private $allowedTypes = array("mp4", "flv", "webm", "mkv", "vob", "ogv", "ogg", "avi", "wmv", "mov", "mpeg", "mpg");

    public function __construct($con) {
        $this->con = $con;
    }

    public function upload($videoUploadData) {

        $targetDir = "uploads/videos/";
        $videoData = $videoUploadData->videoDataArray;

        $tempFilePath = $targetDir . uniqid() . basename($videoData["name"]);
        //uploads/videos/5aa3e9343c9ffdogs_playing.flv

        $tempFilePath = str_replace(" ", "_", $tempFilePath);

        $isValidData = $this->processData($videoData, $tempFilePath);

        if(!$isValidData) {
            return false;
        }

        if(move_uploaded_file($videoData["tmp_name"], $tempFilePath)) {

            $finalFilePath = $targetDir . uniqid() . ".mp4";

            if(!$this->insertVideoData($videoUploadData, $finalFilePath)) {
                echo "Insert query failed";
                return false;
            }

        }
    }

    private function processData($videoData, $filePath) {
        $videoType = pathInfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(!$this->isValidSize($videoData)) {
            echo "File too large. Can't be more than " . $this->sizeLimit . " bytes";
            return false;
        }
        else if(!$this->isValidType($videoType)) {
            echo "Invalid file type";
            return false;
        }
        else if($this->hasError($videoData)) {
            echo "Error code: " . $videoData["error"];
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function isValidSize($data) {
        return $data["size"] <= $this->sizeLimit;
    }

    private function isValidType($type) {
        $lowercased = strtolower($type);
        return in_array($lowercased, $this->allowedTypes);
    }

    private function hasError($data) {
        return $data["error"] != 0;
    }

    private function insertVideoData($uploadData, $filePath) {
        $query = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO videos(title, uploadedBy, description, privacy, category, filePath)
                                        VALUES(:title, :uploadedBy, :description, :privacy, :category, :filePath)");

        $query->bindParam(":title", $uploadData->title);
        $query->bindParam(":uploadedBy", $uploadData->uploadedBy);
        $query->bindParam(":description", $uploadData->description);
        $query->bindParam(":privacy", $uploadData->privacy);
        $query->bindParam(":category", $uploadData->category);
        $query->bindParam(":filePath", $filePath);

        return $query->execute();
    }
}
?>
```

VideoUploadData.php File:

```
<?php
class VideoUploadData {

    public $videoDataArray, $title, $description, $privacy, $category, $uploadedBy;

    public function __construct($videoDataArray, $title, $description, $privacy, $category, $uploadedBy) {
        $this->videoDataArray = $videoDataArray;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->privacy = $privacy;
        $this->category = $category;
        $this->uploadedBy = $uploadedBy;
    }

}
?>
```

processing.php File:

```
<?php 
require_once("includes/header.php");
require_once("includes/classes/VideoUploadData.php");
require_once("includes/classes/VideoProcessor.php");

if(!isset($_POST["uploadButton"])) {
    echo "No file sent to page.";
    exit();
}

// 1) create file upload data
$videoUploadData = new VideoUploadData(
                            $_FILES["fileInput"], 
                            $_POST["titleInput"],
                            $_POST["descriptionInput"],
                            $_POST["privacyInput"],
                            $_POST["categoryInput"],
                            "REPLACE-THIS"    
                        );

// 2) Process video data (upload)
$videoProcessor = new VideoProcessor($con);
$wasSuccessful = $videoProcessor->upload($videoUploadData);

// 3) Check if upload was successful
?>
```

upload.php File:

```
<?php 
require_once("includes/header.php");
require_once("includes/classes/VideoDetailsFormProvider.php");
?>


<div class="column">

    <?php
    $formProvider = new VideoDetailsFormProvider($con);
    echo $formProvider->createUploadForm();
    ?>


</div>


<?php require_once("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: **WAY** To much code please read [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you trying to store video file inside a database?

Comment: yes for now i am trying to store video files path along with its details to mysql database

Comment: SO if the video is in the database WHAT is the `video files path` going to tell you?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's not too much code; I had to use every last bit of it to find the source of the problem.  It made debugging super easy.

Comment: Really @Zenexer? The HTML helped you to solve this? ROFL

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, believe it or not.  Had to make sure it was actually a file being uploaded and not some other craziness.

Comment: @NishantNarola Despite JayBlanchard's rush-to-judgement on your question, he is a seasoned pro and has several [articles](http://www.jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) on his website that you might find interesting. At the least, they are well written and informative.

Answer (score 1):

Per https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php:

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
>
> Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

You should be able to increase `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini to resolve the issue.

Comment: @NishantNarola It's possible that it's not taking effect.  That's definitely what the error code you're receiving represents, since it's coming from `$_FILE[x]['error']`.  Make sure you've restarted Apache (or PHP-FPM) after making the changes and that you're editing the correct file.  It usually needs to be named php.ini; if it's named php.ini.production or something, you need to rename it.

Comment: @NishantNarola If this answer solved your problem, please accept it as the correct answer (by clicking the checkmark to the left) *and* (optionally) upvoting the answer if it was particularly helpful. +1 to Zenexer - good sleuthing.